# Changing size of CustomView in ListView in onTouch-method(setLayoutParams not working)

Tags: android, android-listview, resize, layoutparams, ontouch

I'm having a ListView which is filled by a custom BaseAdapter. 
The getView-method in my custom BaseAdapter only returns a custom View which extends RelativeLayout.

Now I want that whenever I touch a ListView-item the height of this item is set to the Y-Position of the TouchEvent (or to something else but thats not the problem).

So I'm setting a OnTouchListener in my custom View:

```
ViewGroup.OnTouchListener listener = new ViewGroup.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                 break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                    Log.e("ontouchListener: ",((Float)event.getRawY()).toString() + "\n");
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams params =(AbsListView.LayoutParams)getLayoutParams();
                    params.height =(int)event.getRawY();//(int)(startedHeight + (startedY - event.getRawY()));
                    //setLayoutParams(params);  
                    break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                break;  
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

So everything is fine. In my Log I'm seeing tons of numbers running down.
But as soon as I want to call the setLayoutParams-method (which is necessary) it seems that the onTouch-method is only called once and then again when I release and re-touch the screen because I'm now getting just one number in my Log and my custom View also resizes just once.

Any ideas whats the reason for that?